# Indexing issue that doesn't make sense when trying to scrape using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use the script below to go through a list of urls, find the date of each race per url and find the location of each race per url.  I am getting an IndexError for out of range, but I know that the lists that I'm iterating over are all the same length and these errors don't make sense.   Also when runnning through Pycharm I get different points at which the IndexErrors occur when compared to running through terminal.  I wasn't going to post here, but I'm seriously confused and wondering if anyone else can replicate what I'm seeing and has an explanation of what I'm missing.  Here's the code and the list:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('hk_pages.txt', 'r') as urls:
    starting_list = urls.read().split()

for url in starting_list:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # Track
    tracksoup = str(soup.findAll("td", {"class": "racingTitle"}))
    tracklist = tracksoup.split('>')
    track = tracklist[1][:2]

    # Date
    datesoup = str(soup.findAll("td", {"class": "tdAlignL number13 color_black"}))
    datelist = datesoup.split()
    date = datelist[6]

    print(date)
    print(track)
    print("**************************************************")
```

Here's the list of urls:

```
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150906
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150909
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150913
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150916
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150919
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150923
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20150928
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151001
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151004
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151007
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151010
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151014
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151017
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151018
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151022
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151025
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151031
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151101
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151103
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151107
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151108
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151111
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151114
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151118
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151121
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151125
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151129
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151202
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151206
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151209
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151213
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151216
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151219
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151223
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20151227
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160101
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160106
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160109
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160113
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160117
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160120
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160124
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160131
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160203
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160206
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160210
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160214
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160217
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160221
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160224
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160227
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160228
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160302
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160305
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160306
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160309
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160313
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160316
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160319
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160320
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160323
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160326
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160328
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160331
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160402
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160403
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160406
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160409
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160410
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160413
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160416
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160417
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160420
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160424
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160427
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160501
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160504
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160507
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160511
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160514
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160518
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160522
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160529
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160601
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160604
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160605
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160609
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160612
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160614
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160615
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160616
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160618
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160619
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160622
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160626
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160701
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160706
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160710
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160903
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160907
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160911
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160918
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160921
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160925
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20160928
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161001
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161002
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161005
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161008
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161012
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161015
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161016
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161019
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161022
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161023
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161026
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161029
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161030
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161101
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161102
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161105
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161106
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161109
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161112
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161116
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161118
http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/ResultsAll/English/Local/20161120
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(datelist)`?

Comment: It's the str returned from using soup.findall.  For each page there's only one track and one date to be scraped

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? I was assuming it was `date = datelist[6]`? If not, it would help if you show your error message, or at least tell us which line raises the error.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joelmcleod/python/racing/hkscraper.py", line 15, in <module>
    track = tracklist[1][:2]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It's iterating through over the list of urls and the weird thing is that I'll run it and it'll get 3 or 4 urls in and then throw the error, but then I'll run it again straight away and it won't throw an error until halfway through the whole list.  It doesn't make sense, and sometimes it's the datelist index causing the error and sometimes it's the tracklist index.

Comment: That means that `html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)` is not always returning what you think/expect. You will need to put some more debugging print statements throughout your code. The best place to start would be to print `soup` right after assigning it, to make sure the html is actually what you expect, and not a 404 page or 500 page, etc.

Comment: Yeah it's like when I run it once some of the urls will return None, and when I run it again the next time those same urls will now return values and other urls will return None.  It seems random

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Track
    tracksoup = str(soup.findAll("td", {"class": "racingTitle"}))
    tracklist = tracksoup.split('>')
    track = tracklist[1][:2]
```

the problem is you can not `str([item,item...])`, soup.findAll will return a list, if you try this, the out_put will be:

```
'[item,item...]'
```

this is not what you what.